# How can I bind a toggle to the clicked element to mapped data in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using reactstrap/bootstrap for an accordion functionality. I'm having trouble with my toggling and onclick.  My state, function and render look like the following:

```
state = {
    basicFeatures: [],
    fuelEconomy: {},
    upholsteryType: null,
    category: 'Engine',
    collapse: false,
    active: false,
    activeTab: 'capabilities',
};


toggle = active =>
    this.setState({
        collapse: !this.state.collapse,
        active: !this.state.active,
    });

const specsCatsR = this.props.specs.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Col xs="12" key={i} className="border-bottom p-15">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                            icon={
                                this.state.active ? faMinusCircle : faPlusCircle
                            }
                        />
                        <h5 
                            className="collapse-header" 
                            onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}
                            >
                            {' '}
                            {item.category}{' '}
                        </h5>
                        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.active}>
                            <SpecsDetails
                                vehicle={this.props.vehicle}
                                values={item.values}
                                category={item.category}
                            />
                        </Collapse>
                    </Col>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    });
```

It spits out a list of items. However, when I click on one item, they all open/toggle.  How can I bind it to only open the one that is clicked?

Comment: pass the id of the element on onClick and check this in the handler then toggle it accordingly.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example please? I know how to pass it, but the check is what i'm having trouble with. Still learning react.

Comment: What check do you mean?

Comment: How do I check the id in my toggle function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only one of your elements is supposed to be expanded at a time, I recommend storing the `id` of the currently expanded item in your `state` (here in `active`).
The toggle function will receive the `id` of the clicked element and then the `onClick` event arguments by preconfiguring it :

```
state = {
    basicFeatures: [],
    fuelEconomy: {},
    upholsteryType: null,
    category: 'Engine',
    collapse: false,
    active: null, //Active is not a boolean anymore
    activeTab: 'capabilities',
};


toggle = id => ev => { //Add brackets here, you do not need to return the result of setState
    this.setState({
        collapse: !this.state.collapse,
        active: id,
    });
}

const specsCatsR = this.props.specs.map((item, i) => 
        <React.Fragment>
            <Col xs="12" key={i} className="border-bottom p-15">
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={
                        this.state.active ? faMinusCircle : faPlusCircle
                    }
                />
                <h5
                    className="collapse-header"
                    onClick={this.toggle(i)} // bind is not necessary since you are using an arrow function
                >
                    {` ${item.category} `}
                </h5>
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.active === i}> //If the index is the same as the active element id, it expands
                    <SpecsDetails
                        vehicle={this.props.vehicle}
                        values={item.values}
                        category={item.category}
                    />
                </Collapse>
            </Col>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you.